# Linux kernel parameters: what is the difference of net.ifnames=0 and biosdevname=0

Tags: linux, kernel

I find that centos7.8 is using "net.ifnames=0" without "biosdevname=0" in its kernel parameters, the result seems be same: I got traditional nic name such as eth0.

Just curious, what is the difference of "net.ifnames=0" and "biosdevname=0"?

Comment: The way I understand it,  `net.ifnames` tells systemd to create predictable NIC names, whereas `biosdevname` is one of several naming methods, namely Dell's method to derive the interface name from BIOS information using a tool named, you may guess it, `biosdevname`. Documented in the [RHEL networking guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-consistent_network_device_naming_using_biosdevname).

Comment: According to the document, ```Note that unless the system is a Dell system, or biosdevname is explicitly enabled as described in Section 11.6.2, “Enabling and Disabling the Feature”, the systemd naming scheme will take precedence"```, seems for Dell System, I still need set "biosdevname=0" to generate traditional nic names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [dell docs](https://linux.dell.com/files/biosdevname/):

> Biosdevname is a udev helper utility developed by Dell and released under the GNU General Public License (GPL). It provides a consistent naming mechanism for network devices based on their physical location as suggested by the system BIOS.

[From manpages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/biosdevname)

```
biosdevname takes a kernel device name as an argument,
and returns the BIOS-given name it "should" be.
```

The `biosdevname` is enabled by default on systems running RedHat based on Dell hardware.

The `net.ifnames=0` is a kernel parameter that disables the Predictable Network Interface renaming behavior.

[kernel-command-line manpages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-udevd.service.8.html)

```
   net.ifnames=
       Network interfaces are renamed to give them predictable names
       when possible. It is enabled by default; specifying 0
       disables it
```

Comment: thank you very much. WITHOUT "biosdevname=0", will "net.ifnames=0"  alone always generate traditional nic names such as eth0?

Comment: According to the document, ```Note that unless the system is a Dell system, or biosdevname is explicitly enabled as described in Section 11.6.2, “Enabling and Disabling the Feature”, the systemd naming scheme will take precedence"```, seems for Dell System, I still need set "biosdevname=0" to generate traditional nic names.

Comment: I have tested on a DELL server, found that "net.ifnames=0" works WITHOUT "biosdevname=0", that is because the OS image I have used has not even installed the `biosdevname` package which is a prerequisite for biosdevname mechanism.
> For this feature to take effect, the biosdevname package must also be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a complementary,

The `biosdevname` kernel parameter takes effect only when following requirements are met:

- DELL hardware
- `biosdevname` package has been installed